# Is there a way to set Chrome Sync so that everything syncs apart from the home page?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I've got Chrome running at work and home (on XP and OS X respectively), and I have enabled chrome sync.

Unfortunately, at work I have the intranet set as my home/startup-page, which is useless at home.

Is there a way to sync everything else apart from this?

I've noticed that I can customise to a certain degree (i.e. not sync preferences, but I'd like more granular control if it's available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with chrome, but you can surely do this within your network settings.  Here are a few ideas:

**Change Computer Settings**: Set your homepage to www.intranet.com (or whatever your intranet site is at work) on both computers.  Then on your OS X computer at home, in the [hosts file](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291?viewlocale=en_US), create an alias for www.intranet.com to direct you to www.superuser.com or wherever you would like.

**Change Router Settings**: A lot of routers can be configured to this same kind referral.

**Set up external website to refer you based on OS or IP**: Finally, you could set up your own website www.RickyTheGeek.com that detects your OS or IP and then refers you to one or the other website depending on what it detects.

**Create a local file that contains a redirect**: On each computer create a local file in the same spot called homepage.html and in each one put 1 of the following 2 lines:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.intranet.com">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.superuser.com">
```

Since they are different systems you can't put the full directory name like setting your homepage to `file:///C:/homepage.html`, but you should be able to set both homepages to just `file:///homepage.html` as long as you can find out which directory each computer looks in when no  directory is specified.

So there are 4 options to get you started.

Comment: A clever approach. I hadn't thought about that. I'll give that a go until more granular controls are added to Chrome.